# Unity Container does not work with Strongly Types Assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, .net-assembly

I am trying to register a type using Unity :

```
  Container.RegisterType<ICommonInterfaceType, MyTypedClass>("Name001");
```

Here `MyTypedClass` is inside an assembly which signed with a snk. So when I try to resolved, getting this error:

> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'NM.Common.Interface, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
>    A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)

If I removed Sign the assembly option , it works. But is there any way , Unity be able to resolve the strongly signed assemblies.

Comment: I don't see a non-generic overload of IUnityContainer.RegisterType that takes a single String argument. Can you post a full example?

Comment: @lesscode, I did post the full code, but looks like stack oveflow is soing something . If you click on edit , there is full code , Container.RegisterType<ICommonInterfaceType, MyTypedClass>("Name001"); And M editing it now

Comment: NM.Common.Interface is a third assembly (separate from the one containing MyTypedClass)? If so is that common assembly also strong-named?

Comment: @lesscode, MyTypedClass is strongly typed , but NM.Common.Interface (ICommonInterfaceType ) assembly is not strongly typed

Comment: In that case it's nothing to do with Unity. You'd get the same error if you did: ICommonInterfaceType x = new MyTypedClass(). Strong-named assemblies can only reference other strong-named assemblies.